# Side bar acquiring whole body width, cannot insert any other contents on the same line

Tags: php, html, sidebar

I have created a sidebar in a php file, and included it in another webpage using 'include' syntax. The sidebar acquires only 20% of the body width, but I cannot put anything on the remaining 80%... Whatever I try to enter in those space, it comes in ONE LINE BELOW the sidebar. How do I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `float: left;` on both elements to stick them next to each other.

Comment: since both elements are in different files, i need to add float property to the body tag of those files?

Comment: Not the <body> if that's what you mean. The float attribute should be put on those 2 divs you like next to eachother. Optimally you would want to do that through a stylesheet and not inline-css.